Why does "Get-LocalUser" on a Domain Controller lists computernames
Just wondering why Get-LocalUser also lists all AD-Computernames (with a trailing $-sign) when i run it on the Domain Controller.
However, they do not appear with net user.

What research have you done regarding this? Have you at least reviewed the documentation on these commands?

Probably better for Server Fault, but googling and reading over posts, etc. this information can be found. Not sure about searching on SuperUser but try ServerFault.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle thanks, i didn't know about Server Fault and found something there that kinda explains it to me https://serverfault.com/questions/66660/what-does-domain-name-computer-name-mean

Yep, if you use "authenticated users" or "domain computers" for authentication it will likely allow the machine AD domain joined object access to the resource at least when accessed as system.
